# Why Hugo makes nav items plural?

Tags: html, markdown, hugo

I want to make a navbar with Hugo where the navbar is automatically made by using the folder names in the content folder. Except if the folder name doesn't end with 's', it transform the word in plural.

Why does that happen? Can I make Hugo not do that? Or do I need to make a custom menu?
I don't want to use the plural words.

I'm new to Hugo so I just followed the steps to make a sectional navbar.

In the config-file I added:

```
sectionPagesMenu = "main"
```

In my header partial I have:

```
{{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
    <li>
        <a class='nav-item
        {{if or ($currentPage.IsMenuCurrent "main" .) ($currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" .) }}
        active
        {{end}}'
        href="{{ .URL }}" title="{{ .Title }}">{{ .Name }}</a>
    </li>
{{ end }}
```

I expected that Hugo just uses the name of my folders (blog, covers, jewelry) as nav item, but instead it says: blogs, covers, jewelries.

Answer (score 3):

In older versions of Hugo, section names are pluralized by default. In the latest version (0.55.5 as of today), it doesn't do this, though. So, you have two options:

1. Upgrade to the latest version of Hugo; or
2. Stay with your current version, then add custom front matter for each section. For example, for your `blog` section, create file `content/blog/_index.md` then add the following front matter, assuming YAML format:

```
---
title: Blog
---
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to your `config.toml` file:

```
pluralizelisttitles = false
```